# How to Resolve System.web.Httpcontext.Server.MapPath Reference missing

Tags: c#, httpcontext, server.mappath, system.web

I have to create Folder at server with the help of Server.MapPath method in C# but i can't Use HttpContext Class in project, any solution?

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(@"~/pix/"));

it not allow me to use Server.MapPath method

Comment: could you please include code? and let me know what u mean by  `HttpContect`

Comment: If you take a look at [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) page in msdn, you will see the class is in assembly  `System.Web (in System.Web.dll)` and you should add it as reference.

Comment: Yes i  added reference but yet its not allow to add System.Web.HttpContext

Comment: How does it not allow you? What's the error message or symptom?

Comment: Does not exist in Current Context, and even not allow to Use System.web.HttpContext

Comment: Use correct case, `System.Web`

Comment: The type or namespace name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  and Case is Correct

Comment: Are you sure you added the reference of `System.Web.dll` to references in your project?

Comment: Yes I added, is can be Framework problem? because Server.MapPath is not Working but  I tried (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/pix/") that Working  in Framework 4.5 but non of Working in 4.0

Comment: @akshaychavda Also cross check dll runtime versions in properties, if you try accessing higher framework dll in lower framework code, then also this kind of problems can occur. E.g: Accessing .Net4.5 dll from within .Net4.0 project etc.

Comment: yes definitely thank you all help.